# I want to merge two dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Let me describe you the scenario 
I have got two arrays one with second column as 0
and another array with second column with some value,

**first array**

Array

(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-19
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-20
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-21
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-22
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-23
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-24
        [email_data] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-25
        [email_data] => 0
    )
```

**second array**

Array

(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-20
        [email_data] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-21
        [email_data] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [time_frame] => 2017-05-24
        [email_data] => 8
    )
```

)

Now what I want to achieve is the data below:

```
[
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-19",
    "email_data": "0"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-20",
    "email_data": "1"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-21",
    "email_data": "2"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-22",
    "email_data": "0"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-23",
    "email_data": "0"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-24",
    "email_data": "8"
},
{
    "time_frame": "2017-05-25",
    "email_data": "0"
}
```

]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: @ObjectManipulator  i tried finding difference but  I got first array as result https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/780780/PHP-Finding-differences-in-two-multidimensional-ar

Comment: use `array_merge()` php function it work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this piece of code...

```
$data1 = array(
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-19', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-20', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-21', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-22', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-23', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-24', 'email_data'=>0),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-25', 'email_data'=>0)
    );


$data2 = array(
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-20', 'email_data'=>1),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-21', 'email_data'=>2),
        array('time_frame'=>'2017-05-24', 'email_data'=>8)
    );


foreach ($data2 as $key2 => $value2)
{
    foreach ($data1 as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        if($value2['time_frame'] == $value1['time_frame']) {
            $data1[$key1] = $value2;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data1);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you do it using loop, php provide `array_merge()` function use it
example is here..

first array..

```
$first = array(
        0 => Array
            (
                "time_frame" => "2017-05-20",
                "email_data" => "1"
            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                "time_frame" => "2017-05-21",
                "email_data" => "2"
            ),

        2 => Array
            (
                "time_frame" => "2017-05-24",
                "email_data" => "8"
            )
);
```

second array...

```
$second = array(
            0 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-19",
                    "email_data" => 0
                ),

            1 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-20",
                    "email_data" => 0
                ),

            2 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-21"
                    ,"email_data" => 0
                ),

            3 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-22"
                    ,"email_data" => 0
                ),

            4 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-23"
                    ,"email_data" => 0
                ),

            5 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-24"
                    ,"email_data" => 0
                ),

            6 => Array
                (
                    "time_frame" => "2017-05-25"
                    ,"email_data" => 0
                )
    );
```

now your solutions is here..

```
$combined_array = array_merge($first,$second);
```

and it give you required result. Simple.

for printing result...

```
foreach($combined_array as $key){
        print_r($key);
        echo "<br> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - <br>";
    }
```

Comment: .............................

    [6] => Array
        (
            [time_frame] => 2017-05-25
            [email_data] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [time_frame] => 2017-05-20
            [email_data] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [time_frame] => 2017-05-21
            [email_data] => 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [time_frame] => 2017-05-24
            [email_data] => 8
        )

)
this is output of your code 
it is not what i need

Comment: you wanna json data?